# Android opencv new mat error

Tags: android, opencv, mat

The following is the piece of code that I am trying to execute

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.cat); 

    Bitmap footbm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

    temp = new Mat (footbm.getHeight(),footbm.getWidth() , CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(footbm, temp);  
    Imgproc.cvtColor(temp, temp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);  
    Bitmap grayBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(footbm.getWidth(), footbm.getHeight(), Config.RGB_565);  

    Utils.matToBitmap(temp, grayBmp);  

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setImageBitmap(grayBmp); 
}
```

And it gives an error as shown below

> No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(int, int,
>   int) (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and
>   Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__III) compile is successful.

I guess that the error is due to this statement.

```
temp = new Mat (footbm.getWidth(),footbm.getHeight() , CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

Kindly suggest how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot execute any opencv code in **onCreate**() since the native so's are not loaded yet

move your code to **onCameraViewStarted**();

Answer (score 1):

```
Execute your code in BaseLoaderCallback
======================================================================
private BaseLoaderCallback mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
             //your code
        }
            break;
        default: {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
            break;
        }
    }
};
======================================================================
put this line in your onCreate
if (!OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2,
                    MainActivity.this, mOpenCVCallBack)) {
                Log.e("TEST", "Cannot connect to OpenCV Manager");
            }
```